# How do I change the display name of my Expo app?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm building a react native app for iOS using expo. My app development build currently the ugliest name imaginable as it's app name, when shown on the screen.

[image: app-icon]

I tried multiple different ways to change it, but it seems to be inherently linke to the slug. What am I supposed to change? I already changed the name in app.json and updated the app version and rebuilt it, but nothing's changed after reinstalling

My app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "NewName",
    "slug": "rn_app",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "icon":"./assets/images/Icon1024.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splashscreens/LaunchImage.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#262628"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {

      }
    },
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.0.2",

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the managed Expo flow?

Comment: Have you tried these steps? -- https://hemanthkollanur.medium.com/how-to-change-rename-the-app-name-in-react-native-in-android-and-ios-7486653b3362

Comment: @tomerpacific I do

Comment: @server_unknown This does not work for expo